# How to override out of box extension in SAP Hybris Commerce?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to override OOTB extension provided by SAP Hybris commerce with our own custom extension. Say for example I want replace "catalog" with our own implementation. Please put some light on this question.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some more insight? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

While it might be somehow technically possible (you could rewrite the catalog extension and replace the old one with your one in your build mechanism maybe), this is not the recommended approach to customizing and enhancing hybris.
Instead, you would create your own extension (using the ext-gen mechanism documented well on help.hybris.com) and enhance (i.e. add new item types, attributes etc) or even just redeclare existing item types and attributes.

The catalog extension is part of the core platform, it is designed to be fairly generic and extensible, do you have any particular reason to replace it instead of enhancing/redeclaring things on it?

Hope this helps

Comment: in addition to the answer, any Spring bean (and thus all functionality) may be overriden in your custom extension